# I am trying to join two table but getting the error as Invalid object name

Tags: sql

I want to Write a SQL script, which would return all the Employees in EmployeeMaster table with the columns LastName, City, State and Country.

This is what I tried to execute but it shows error.

```
SELECT dbo.EmployeeMaster.LastName, dbo.EmployeeDetails.City, State, Country
From dbo.EmployeeMaster
LEFT JOIN EmployeeDetails 
ON dbo.EmployeeMaster.ID=dbo.EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID
ORDER BY dbo.EmployeeMaster.LastName
```

Comment: If you could post the full error message it would be help.

Comment: assuming that not all employees have details that's why you are using Left Join?

Comment: you don't suppose the error message that you are receiving might be at least slightly pertinent to the problem at hand?

Comment: you don't suppose that the table definitions (in the form of `CREATE TABLE` statements) might be slightly useful for answering your question?

Comment: Please reformat your SQL statement as code and use proper indentations

Comment: This is the task that I want to do.      “EmployeeMaster” Table with following columns:
 Id (Primary Key)
 First Name 
 Last Name

2.  “EmployeeDetails”  Table with following columns:
 EmployeeId(Foreign Key to Id column of EmployeeMaster table)
 City
 State
 Country
 Phone

3. Write a SQL script to insert below mentioned three rows in both the EmployeeMaster table 

i. 1, “Prasad”,”Kumar”
ii. 2, “Amar”, “Singh”
iii. 3, “Sunny”, “Patel”

Comment: 4. Write a SQL script to insert below mentioned three rows in both the EmployeeDetails table 

iv. 1, “Charlotte”,”NC”, “US”, “45465462”
v. 2, “Columbus”,”OH”, “US”, “894543”
vi. 2, “Amritsar”,”PJ”, “India”, “3434334”
5. Write a SQL script, which would return the columns First Name, City, State, Country and Phone whose address is present in the EmployeeDetails table

Comment: Write a SQL script, which would return all the Employees in EmployeeMaster table with the columns LastName, City, State and Country .                   7. Write a SQL script, which would return the columns First Name, City, State, Country and Phone whose Id is 2.

Comment: As other said, you need to reformat your query as code, add the tables defintions in the main post as well, and add the error message your question was about.
Asking other to just do your assignement isn't how stackoverflow work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing dbo prefixe on your left join no ? Since you are sing it on the `ON`, `ORDER`  and `SELECT`

```
SELECT dbo.EmployeeMaster.LastName, dbo.EmployeeDetails.City, State, Country 
From dbo.EmployeeMaster 
LEFT JOIN dbo.EmployeeDetails ON dbo.EmployeeMaster.ID=dbo.EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID 
ORDER BY dbo.EmployeeMaster.LastName
```

Not sure which table State & ountry are from, hoping they are not in both table else you need to add their table alias.